# upload image in public folder in react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I want to upload an image and it should be added in the public folder, I am passing the image through API and in the webs public folder, this image should be added.

```
 myReader.onloadend = () => {
           this.photo = myReader.result.toString();
   };]
        this.photo_name = oldFileItem+'.'+'jpg';
        var imgFile = new File([file], this.photo_name, {type:file.type});
        console.log(imgFile);
        myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
   
        data.photo = this.photo;
        data.imageurl = this.imageurl;
        data.photo_name = this.photo_name ;
```

and this data is passed through API and should be uploaded in the image folder.

Comment: You want to upload the image in the frontend?